# How can I listen for DragDataReceived in a TreeView when the Model is a TreeModelSort?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#

I have a TreeView whose Model is a TreeModelSort with a ListStore as its child. I would like this TreeView to listen to DragDataReceived. However, when I drag data to it, I get this warning:

> (TestDragDrop:4706): Gtk-WARNING **:
>   You must override the default
>   'drag_drop' handler on GtkTreeView
>   when using models that don't support
>   the GtkTreeDragDest interface and
>   enabling drag-and-drop. The simplest
>   way to do this is to connect to
>   'drag_drop' and call
>   g_signal_stop_emission_by_name() in
>   your signal handler to prevent the
>   default handler from running. Look at
>   the source code for the default
>   handler in gtktreeview.c to get an
>   idea what your handler should do.
>   (gtktreeview.c is in the GTK source
>   code.) If you're using GTK from a
>   language other than C, there may be a
>   more natural way to override default
>   handlers, e.g. via derivation.

I'm a bit lost on how to do thisin Gtk#. The message says "If you're using GTK from a language other than C, there may be a more natural way to override default handlers, e.g. via derivation." Can someone point me to an example of what this would look like? What exactly am I overriding? There is no DragDrop method, and overriding OnDragDataReceived doesn't seem to work. Alternatively, I could manually sort the ListStore, but that seems like a really bad idea (especially since there doesn't seem to be any easy way to swap elements).

Here is an example TreeView for reference:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Gtk;

namespace TestDragDrop
{
    public class DestTreeView : TreeView
    {
        public DestTreeView ()
        {
            ListStore store = new ListStore (typeof (string));
            TreeModelSort sort = new TreeModelSort (store) { DefaultSortFunc = BarSortFunc };
            Model = sort;

            TreeViewColumn column = new TreeViewColumn { Title = "Bar" };
            CellRendererText cell = new CellRendererText ();
            column.PackStart (cell, true);
            column.SetCellDataFunc (cell, RenderBar);
            AppendColumn (column);

            EnableModelDragDest (Constants.Targets, Gdk.DragAction.Link);
            DragDataReceived += HandleDragDataReceived;

            store.AppendValues ("bar1");
            store.AppendValues ("bar2");
        }

        string GetValueAtPos (int x, int y)
        {
            TreePath path;
            TreeViewDropPosition pos;
            if (!GetDestRowAtPos (x, y, out path, out pos))
                return "";

            TreeIter iter;
            if (!Model.GetIter (out iter, path))
                return "";

            return (string) Model.GetValue (iter, 0);
        }

        void HandleDragDataReceived (object o, DragDataReceivedArgs args)
        {
            string text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString (args.SelectionData.Data);
            string val = GetValueAtPos (args.X, args.Y);

            Console.WriteLine ("Data: '{0}'\nRow: '{1}'", text, val);
        }

        void RenderBar (TreeViewColumn column, CellRenderer renderer, TreeModel model, TreeIter iter)
        {
            ((CellRendererText) renderer).Text = (string) model.GetValue (iter, 0);
        }

        int BarSortFunc (TreeModel model, TreeIter iter1, TreeIter iter2)
        {
            string bar1 = (string) model.GetValue (iter1, 0);
            string bar2 = (string) model.GetValue (iter2, 0);

            return bar1.CompareTo (bar2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The default handler for drag_drop in Gtk# is Widget.OnDragDrop.  So you would need to subclass TreeView and override that virtual method to preempt TreeView's built-in TreeDragDest mechanism.

This signature for OnDragDrop is:

protected virtual bool OnDragDrop (Gdk.DragContext context, int x, int y, uint time_)